# Pass data from ViewController back to root ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uistoryboardsegue

I wonder how I can pass data between VC3 and VC1.

What I have is a root view(VC1). Then you enter a tableView and if you pick an item you will enter tableView2(VC3) - category - sub category picker.

What I have done so far is to declare this in VC1:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

 }
```

Then in story board I control-dragged the yellow button to the red button in VC3 and choose "unwindToVC1" as the action, then I named the segue.

I then fire the segue in VC3 by `performSegueWithIdentifier()`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Vc1" {
            let toView = segue.destinationViewController as! myRootVc

            let test = "test string"

            toView.test = test

        }
    }
```

It almost works, I end up in VC1 but the passed value shows up as nil in VC1, even though I have it declared in vc1 since before:

var test: String?

Comment: Could you add a break point between the if {}. maybe you set the identifier wrong. I don' see other explanations. you code looks fine.

Comment: `if segue.identifier == "Vc1"`. Where us "Vc1" ?

Comment: @Yuchen I tried it and it gets called, so no idea whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

you are using segues to pass data between VC! and VC3 an when you have selcted anitem from sub category. you can use **Delegates**

Comment: But does delegate work between root - child - child VC ? I mean passing it 2 steps back

Comment: @user2722667 I'ld recommend NSNOtificationCenter and posting  a notification